# Can I change gaussian blur radius during FS on already applied areas?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, frequency-separation

I'm trying to master retouch technique `Frequency Separation`, I applied `Gaussian Blur` radius 10 but now I see that it's toomuch for my image, when I change it to lower number it's not affecting on already applied areas. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @user1118321 In all fairness the OP did tag the question with "photoshop" so he did indicate the application in use.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed that!

Comment: I don't think it can be done without starting over on a new copy of your base layer - though I'd be happy to be proven wrong :) As no-one's picked up on this yet, I'm tempted to say it might be a better fit for [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions) than photography. There are some good retouchers on there who may be more au fait with the technique.

Comment: @Tetsujin - proven wrong :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm slightly unsure what you're going for but, I believe the question to essentially be: "Can I change the Gaus. Blur amount after it's already been applied to a layer?" *(If I've misinterpreted, please let me know)*

The answer, unfortunately, is both yes, and no.

Filters, by default, are "destructive" in that their change is applied to the layer and, by default, there's no easy undo button. (Yes, you can go back in history, but if you make a change early in editing...you get up a creek real fast)

That being said, if you first convert the layer to a "Smart Object" (right click on it and convert to Smart Object) - then, any filter applied (almost any filter, there are some caveats) will apply as a [Smart Filter (link to Adobe Help for Smart Filters)](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/applying-smart-filters.html).

This will appear under the layer just like a layer property and will allow you to change the filter settings at any time. I'm happy to report to you that Gaus. Blur is one of the filters that is editable using this method. Cheers,

Comment: Nice one! I've yet to really get into Smart Objects - guess I'll have to do some work ;)